# How to remove the focus in the jquery ui autocomplete custom data and display

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have implemented the jquery ui autocomplete as in the example: [autocomplete with custom data and diplay](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data)
I have some problems with the focus. The users continue to type in the box with the mouse over the menu so I want to remove the focus. The problem is that as soon as I comment the 
**//focus:** 
when the user select an Item it doesn't fire the select event but just the changeEvent and the ui item is null so I can't know who was the selected Item.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What browser are you testing with?

Comment: all browsers - i found the problem so I will give the answer by my self again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just comment the focus: part but be sure not to have a handler for the .blur or .change if you have one the jquery ui autocomplete doesn't apply the selected value, and doesn't fire the select handler